Help needed for Lean4 book Interlude exercise
In 3. Interlude of the Functional Programming in Lean book, one of the exercises asks the reader to prove by simp some few theorems, one of them is "Hello, ".append "world" = "Hello, world". However, when I write
theorem appendHelloWorld : "Hello, ".append "world" = "Hello, world" := by simp

I get an error message telling that simp made no progress. How should I write the theorem to solve the exercise?

I agree, by simp doesn’t work in the current version of Lean.  by rfl does work however.  I would make an issue on the book’s GitHub or reach out to the author.

Perhaps you need to tell Lean what to simplify.
theorem appendHelloWorld : "Hello, ".append "world" = "Hello, world" := by simp [String.append]

I think it is a bug. It seems like a commit caused this regression.
Lean changed the default behavior of simp since 4.3.0

The current default is that simp will call decide to discharge goals. This is a change from Lean 3, potentially expensive, and not relied on by anything in this repository (i.e. CI passes here).
Could we consider changing the default to decide := false.

See also this.

A regression in the book or in Lean?

I thought previously Lean’s simp would run rfl at the end (unlike Coq’s simplify), but now it doesn’t seem to do that.  I wonder if that is intended behavior?

The behavior of simp was changed since 4.3.0 (I tested on my computer). I noticed the change related to simp is chore: change simp default to decide := false by @collares in #2722

@JasonRute https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/pull/1888 says that the default behavior of simp that uses the decidable instances to discard goals seems expensive so they just disabled the default one.
